# How to crawl YouTube video id by using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

If I don't use YouTube Data API, crawl data by using python scrapy. Can it be done ?

I check the root step by step, but I have no idea why I get empty list. Dose YouTube block something on website ?

I want to get href value `29UMdKC2ZTY` from `<a id="thumbnail" />`

```
<a id="thumbnail" class="yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" rel="null" href="/watch?v=29UMdKC2ZTY"></a>
```

Here is what I try:

```
import scrapy

class MoviesintheatersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'MoviesInTheaters'
    allowed_domains = ['youtube.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=food+luck']

    def parse(self, response):
        # Step 1 : I can see tag data
        videoList1 = response.xpath('.//div[@id="container"]')
        # Step 2 : It is empty list
        videoList2 = response.xpath('.//div[@id="container"]/div[@id="dismissible"]')
        print(videoList)
```

settings.py

```
# Scrapy settings for moviescrapy2021 project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'moviescrapy2021'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['moviescrapy2021.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'moviescrapy2021.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'moviescrapy2021 (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'
#USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1'
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36'
# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'moviescrapy2021.middlewares.Moviescrapy2021SpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'moviescrapy2021.middlewares.Moviescrapy2021DownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

#Middleware

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
}
#Selenium

from shutil import which
SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('chromedriver')
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['-headless']  # '--headless' if using chrome instead of firefox

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'moviescrapy2021.pipelines.Moviescrapy2021Pipeline': 300,
#}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest go for BS4 and helium instead Scrapy;  you will get Id's

```
x = (soup.find_all('a','ytd-grid-video-renderer'))
for i in x:
    print(i.text.encode("ascii", "ignore").decode("utf-8", "ignore").strip(),'\t',urljoin(url,i.attrs['href']))
```

Comment: Thanks, I just thought `scrapy` is more popular framework, so I try to use it, I will try your code for BS4, thanks.

Comment: Yes! Scrapy is good for Bot and other  works. Even, I was started with Scrapy. However, nowadays will use more simpler then Scrapy. Like, requests_HTML, BS4 is more enough. When you face JS bases site then find flexible doodler, flask and hilium.

Answer (score -1):

You xpath is incorrect. You can use `//a[@id='thumbnail']/@href` to get a list of thumbnails and iterate over them one by one.

Comment: I know `//a[@id='thumbnail']/@href`, but my problem is I can't get data from outside root.

Comment: `I can't get data from outside root`
Could you elaborate?

Comment: If `xpath('.//div[@id="container"]/div[@id="dismissible"]')` is empty , then even I try `//a[@id='thumbnail']/@href` is still empty, some one told me that I have to use Selenium because the data generate by javascript, doesn't know why they just delete the response.

Comment: Can you try setting `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` inside your settings.py?

Comment: I have already set the rule, I update question about settings.py